# tumblr javascript embed with css skin

Tags: javascript, html, css, tumblr

I am trying to add a single most recent tumblr post to another page.
I found the easiest way is to use the Javascript code provided by tumblr

here is what they offered:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://occupy837.tumblr.com/js"></script>
```

adding ?num specifies the number of posts, so I can see that I am almost there

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://occupy837.tumblr.com/js?num=1"></script>
```

when I go to the page
(www.Occupy837.com) One single post shows up!
my only issue now is that it has a single 1 on the left of the post

tumblr quotes "[use the] code to embed your posts as basic HTML that you can skin with CSS:"

Does anyone have any idea how I can remove that number?! what do I have to do with CSS to make that disappear!

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your css

```
li.tumbler-post {
  list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: OH NO! I figured it was something that simple, but It is not working! is this something that can only be applied to the tumblr css? when added to an external page should it still operate? I figured that you ment to type "tumblr" instead of "tumbler" no luck, then I tried .tumblr {
        list-style: none;
}     No such luck either, any help?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer!

after doing some research I found this to be the solution:

```
ol.tumblr_posts{

    list-style:none;
}
```

be careful not to type "tumbler" because it is always without the "e"

Answer (score 0):

My friend ran into this last night and tumblr exactly provides something that is pretty decent but with very few documentation. Every tumblr post has CSS classes. The above answers work. If you need to know more about the classes tumblr provides right click a post and click inspect element.

You can add these classes to the CSS of your website. Adjusting the CSS of tumblr doesn't effect it.

Adding the above CSS will fix this issue.