# Tumblr JS Embed CSS/HTML Tags for Styling?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tumblr

I used tumblr's javascript embed code to embed my posts into an external website. Now I want to style the posts. Where can I find the full list of tags, classes, and all of that in order to do this? I see people posting some of the tags, for exampe ol.tumblr_posts, but no one has said how or where they actually found out that's the tag tumblr is using for that particular element.

Someone mentioned using the web developer extension in Firefox to pull out the HTML associated with the javascript file but I can't use Firefox so I need another suggestion? I did go to tumblr's docs but the tags and everything used for customizing themes WITHIN tumblr seem to be different from the ones used to display posts outside of tumblr.

I also looked around in the api section and didn't see anything that lists all of the tags. Thanks!

UPDATE: Here's a post that discusses what I'm talking about but none of the people giving answers that show what tags to use to format the script's output say how or where they got the tags.

[tumblr javascript embed with css skin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9903590/tumblr-javascript-embed-with-css-skin)

This website is the one that said to use the FF add on but again, the person who figures out how to find the tags using it doesn't say HOW, they just say it worked. I'm finally in a place where I can use Firefox so I installed this web developer thing and I still don't see where I would go to see the info that shows the actual html with all the styles instead of just showing the link to the js code.

http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=745299

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! Unfortunately, the only way I could do this was to use the Firefox Web Developer Toolbar Add-On. Once you have that installed, you go to the webpage where you've embedded your blog's javascript code.

Then, in the Firefox toolbar, there should be a tab that says "Miscellaneous". Click on that, then click on "Edit HTML". A new pane opens up towards the bottom of the browser. Inside, it will show the source of the webpage INCLUDING the information that the javascript code generates, which shows the classes, html, and all of that.

It's still not a ton that you can customize compared to using the api (which I don't know how to do) but it's a start. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Chrome and Opera's developer console is CTRL + SHIFT + I... try looking in the source there

IE's dev tools is f12 if you can't use Chrome

Also: I'm not sure if this is what you're talking about but I'll throw in this link for good measure:

http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes

Comment: Thanks! I'll try the dev console and see what it shows. What I'm talking about is on http://www.tumblr.com/goodies, there's an embed code <script type="text/javascript" src="http://yourblog.tumblr.com/js"></script> that you can put in your external website to display your tumblr posts on it but without formatting. I'm looking for the tags to format it. The ones on the site you posted I already know about. That's for working with themes within tumblr. None of them do anything for formatting the output of the javascript code as far as I saw.

Comment: add console output to your qustion

Comment: Sorry vlad, I don't see how to use that console to input anything into it and it doesn't say anything if I try to put in what the javascript outputs. Here's an example of the JS. Using the new yorker's journal for example it's <script type="text/javascript" src="http://newyorker.tumblr.com/js"></script>. If you put that into an external website, it'll generate posts from that blog without formatting. If you view the source, it only shows that same line of script. I don't see how to find out what tags to use to format the data from there and tumblr support won't answer design or code questions.